# Is it ugly to use centered text everywhere and if so how do I know where to put and not put it?

Tags: website-design, web

I am creating a website for myself and I need to know, is it ugly/weird to put centered text everywhere? If I could have some opinions/feedback on [my website](https://onyxdesign.me) that would be great.

Comment: Sorry for that, I didn't disable Coming Soon mode. It should be live now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't be ugly/weird if you use it carefully for some blocks on a website. But if you're going to show much information your users can have difficulties to read it because in western culture people read from left to right and uneven edges of texts will do discomfort for them.

Comment: How do I know where to and not to put centered text?

Comment: You can create two options of a website page. One with left alignment and another centered and then show it to your 3-5 friends. Their opinion will help you understand which approach more comfortable and familiar.